# Sorting a treemap not really working

Tags: java, android, sorting, treemap

I have a nested treemap based on the following structure, and then it ofc continues from "2":{ with the same structure..

http://pastebin.com/uKwAVz5L

And as you can see, it is already sorted by the "c13" sub item (episode number).. but when i use the treemap in my applications, it shows up like this:

http://i50.tinypic.com/15o9vno.png

They are not even remotely sorted.. but i cant see why? :O

Its the same problem when using it in my android app..

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some valuable infomation on [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> Red-Black tree based implementation of the SortedMap interface. *This
>   class guarantees that the map will be in ascending key order, sorted
>   according to the natural order for the key's class* (see **[Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)**),
>   or by the comparator provided at creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used.
>
> Note that the **ordering maintained by a sorted map** (whether or not an
>   explicit comparator is provided) **must be consistent with equals** if
>   this sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface. (See
>   Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with
>   equals.) **This is so because the Map interface is defined in terms of
>   the equals operation, but a map performs all key comparisons using its
>   compareTo (or compare) method**, so two keys that are deemed equal by
>   this method are, from the standpoint of the sorted map, equal. The
>   behavior of a sorted map is well-defined even if its ordering is
>   inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract
>   of the Map interface.

Have you correctly implemented the methods mentioned above?

There are also different implementations of the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/collections/index.html) framework (An overview is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/collections/overview.html)). If TreeMap doesn't provide the functionality you want you can implement another one and modify it to your needs.

Comment: Ehmm, im not quite sure what this means :s?

Comment: Here is the code where i put together the maps.. i kinda know its not super efficient, but i couldn't make it work in any other ideas.. (other optimization ideas are welcome?)

http://pastebin.com/AhpWZNg8

Comment: I have highlighted some important parts and added some links containing all the information needed to work with collections. I believe this sentence says it all: *The behavior of a sorted map is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Map interface"*

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Comparator:

```
TreeMap map = new TreeMap<Obj1, Obj2>(new ObjComparator());

private class ObjComparator() implements Comparator<Obj1> {
    public int compareTo(Obj1 o1, Obj1 o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2); // do your logic here
    }
}
```